# PHPExcel export data in order to excel

Tags: php, mysql, phpexcel

I'm trying to export data in the correct order inside one single xlsx file.

This code below works, but it puts all data into a xlsx file. It pretty much dumps all the data from my database in whatever order it currently is inside the database, into the spreadsheet

```
eg.
ID  Name    Type    Amount
1   aaaa   Income   20
2   bbbb   Exped    30
3   cccc   Income   40
```

What I am trying to do is to sort it out and put the same ones together
eg. what it should look like in excel:

```
row1: ID    Name    Type    Amount
row2: INCOME
row3: 1     aaaa    Income  20
row4: 3     cccc    Income  40



row6: EXPENDITURE
row7: 2     bbbb    Exped   30
```

Any ideas on how I can achieve this?
Below is my code. Cheers,

```
/** Query 1.0 */
    $query = "SELECT * FROM financial";

    if ($result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error())) {
/** Create a new PHPExcel object 1.0 */
   $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
   $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Data');
   }  

    /**HEADINGS*/
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A1', 'FINANCIAL_ID');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('B1', 'TYPE');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('C1', 'NAME');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('D1', 'YEAR');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('E1', 'AMOUNT');

/** Loop through the result set 1.0 */
    $rowNumber = 2; //start in cell 1
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
       $col = 'A'; // start at column A
       foreach($row as $cell) {
          $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue($col.$rowNumber,$cell);
          $col++;
       }
       $rowNumber++;
}
```

Comment: +1 I had no idea you could increment a character like that. cool stuff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get all the types to start:

```
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT Type FROM financial";
$types = mysql_fetch_array($query);
```

And then loop through each type getting their data individually:

```
foreach($types as $type){
    $query = "SELECT * FROM financial WHERE TYPE='$type'";
    while($row = mysql_fetch_row($query)){
        // Output your data into the spreadsheet
    }

    // Get the subtotal for each type.
    $query = "SELECT SUM(Amount) as total FROM financial WHERE Type='$type'";
    $result = mysql_fetch_array($query);
    $subtotal = $result['total'];
    // Add the subtotal to the spreadsheet

    $row += 5; // Skip a few rows in between if you want
}

// Get the Total for everything
$query = "SELECT SUM(Amount) as total FROM financial";
$result = mysql_fetch_array($query);
$total = $result['total'];
// Add the total to the spreadsheet
```

Comment: yeap i've already done that. the income will show no problem. its just the 2nd part: expenditure which will go below the subtotal of income, i'm not too sure how to put the data there. from this code, the rownumber is selected manually. how do I make it choose the next available/empty row?

Comment: So you are looking to add the subtotal column when you are done with a certain type? then add the total at the end when you're through all the types? Not sure I fully understand yet.

Comment: i might leave the subtotal and total for later. ill edit the question

Comment: @Tuzki I updated my answer, I think it is more of what you are looking for.